# Why can my for each loop not print out the contents of an array but a for loop will?

Tags: java

I have two loops that are intended to print of the contents of an array. 
Why does this work:

```
for ( int k = 0 ; k < array.length; k++){
    System.out.print ( array[k] + " ");
}
```

and not this:

```
for ( int k : array ){
    System.out.print ( array[k] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ( int k : array ){
    System.out.print ( array[k] + " ");
}
```

k here is the actual integer data in the array and not the index. You should do

```
for ( int k : array ){
    System.out.print ( k );
}
```

Comment: so it already is the contents of the array meaning I can just do   "System.out.print (k + " ")?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if you want to print index and value at that index.

```
int arr[] ={10,20,30};
int i = 0;
for ( int k : arr ){
  System.out.println ( " element at index "+ i++ + " - " + k);
}
```